# Comparing values to an overall average

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to divide each EPSF1 value from `ticker=7203` JT Equity by the average `EPSF1` value over `66,000` rows  I am not sure how to combine these two queries

```
select Date, Ticker,EPSF1 
from tblForecasts 
where EPSF1 is not null 
and Ticker='7203 jt equity'

select AVG(epsf1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable, store the average there, then use it in your query:

```
declare @avg decimal
select @avg = AVG(epsf1) from tblForecasts 

select Date, Ticker,EPSF1 / @avg
from tblForecasts 
where EPSF1 is not null 
and Ticker='7203 jt equity'
```